require() of ES Module ~/node_modules/adminjs/index.js from ~/dist/adminjs/components/componenLoader.js not supported in nestjs adminjs component
situation

trying to make custom component for showing panel of array type attribute's element (not for showing only array's Length like image)
enter image description here
i want to make it like this



Preferences
field




el1, el2, el3



el1, el3




error

/Users/project/path/dist/adminjs/components/componentLoader.js:19
const _adminjs = require("adminjs");
                 ^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /Users/project/path/node_modules/adminjs/index.js from /Users/project/path/dist/adminjs/components/componentLoader.js not supported.

Instead change the require of index.js in /Users/project/path/dist/adminjs/components/componentLoader.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.

project environment

nestjs / node version 18.20.3 / npm ver 10.7.0 / npx ver 10.7.0
package.json 
...
  "type": "commonjs",
  "dependencies": {
    "@adminjs/express": "^6.1.0",
    "@adminjs/prisma": "^5.0.3",
    "adminjs": "^7.8.1",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "express-formidable": "^1.2.0",
    "express-session": "^1.18.0",
...

tsconfig.json 
...
    "jsx": "react",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "ES6",
...

code

adminjs.module.ts 
import { Components } from './components/componentLoader';

export const dynamicImport = async (packageName: string) =>
  new Function(`return import('${packageName}')`)();
...
const AOptions = {
  listProperties: [
    'email',
    'preferences',
  ],
  sort: {
    direction: 'desc',
    sortBy: 'createdAt',
  },
  properties: {
    preferences: {
      type: 'string',
      isArray: true,
      components: {
        list: Components.ArrayListComponent,
      },
    },
  },
};


@Module({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: 'ADMIN_JS',
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        const AdminJS = (await dynamicImport('adminjs')).default;
        const { ComponentLoader } = await dynamicImport('adminjs');
        const componentLoader = new ComponentLoader();
        const AdminJSPrisma = await dynamicImport('@adminjs/prisma');

        AdminJS.registerAdapter({
          Resource: AdminJSPrisma.Resource,
          Database: AdminJSPrisma.Database,
        });

        const admin = new AdminJS({
          componentLoader: componentLoader,
          resources: [
            {
              resource: {
                model: AdminJSPrisma.getModelByName('A'),
                client: prisma,
              },
              options: AOptions,
            },
          ],
          databases: [],
          rootPath: '/admin',
        });
...


componentLoader.ts 
import { ComponentLoader } from 'adminjs';

export const componentLoader = new ComponentLoader();

export const Components = {
  ArrayListComponent: componentLoader.add(
    'ArrayListComponent',
    './components/array-list.component',
  ),
};

array-list.component.tsx 
import { BasePropertyProps } from 'adminjs';
import React from 'react';

const ArrayListComponent: React.FC<BasePropertyProps> = (props) => {
  const { record, property } = props;
  const items = record.params[property.path] || [];

  return (
    <div>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <div key={index}>{item}</div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ArrayListComponent;

componentLoader.js 
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});
function _export(target, all) {
    for(var name in all)Object.defineProperty(target, name, {
        enumerable: true,
        get: all[name]
    });
}
_export(exports, {
    componentLoader: function() {
        return componentLoader;
    },
    Components: function() {
        return Components;
    }
});
const _adminjs = require("adminjs");
const componentLoader = new _adminjs.ComponentLoader();
const Components = {
    // other custom components
    // 'CustomComponent' is the component name from library
    ArrayListComponent: componentLoader.add('ArrayListComponent', './components/array-list.component')
};

despite of applying dynamic import for commonjs, why does require import applied in js file ? and how can i fix it ?
Did I misapply dynamic calls?
